# android studio 2.2.2 not launch mobile network setting page through code

Tags: android, mobile, settings

now i am working in **android studio 2.2.2** tool.In my app if no internet connection then i should open mobile network setting page.

I am using this code

```
 Intent intent=new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS);
 ComponentName cName = new ComponentName("com.android.phone","com.android.phone.Settings");
 intent.setComponent(cName);
```

once i click setting in popup its moving to mobile network more setting page not moving to setting page.It should move to setting page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use this to launch mobile data settings

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NETWORK_OPERATOR_SETTINGS), MOBILE_DATA_REQUEST_CODE);
```

> Use this to launch mobile data settings

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS), WIFI_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Use

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);}
```